# PhantomJS:page.onError - msg: TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am building a workflow where user can get result after sending query.In this case user will send peptide sequence and then it will display the result. It is working perfectly for FireFox driver but when I am trying to test with PhantomJS for headless browser, it is throwing error.
Selenium version:2.53.1
PhantomJS version:2.1.1

The Java code:

```
package phantomjs;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;
import org.w3c.dom.DOMException;
public class ExtractData {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, DOMException, IOException {
        String userpepseq="NLAVSQVVHK";
        WebDriver drivermassive = new PhantomJSDriver();
        drivermassive.get("http://exmaple.com/xyz_search.jsp");
        System.out.println(drivermassive.getTitle());
        WebElement searchdatapeptideseq=drivermassive.findElement(By.name("peptide"));
        System.out.println(searchdatapeptideseq.isDisplayed());
        searchdatapeptideseq.sendKeys(userpepseq);
        WebElement datasetbutton=drivermassive.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='proxi-selector' and contains (@onclick,'datasets')]"));
        datasetbutton.click();
        System.out.println(datasetbutton.isDisplayed());
        System.out.println(drivermassive.getCurrentUrl());
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        String sCellValuemassid = drivermassive.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='result']/tbody")).getText();
        System.out.println(sCellValuemassid);
        drivermassive.quit();
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[ERROR - 2016-09-26T23:24:35.321Z] Session [61de22a0-8440-11e6-9376-7b90c4d612ac] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'query.startsWith("#")')

  phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
[ERROR - 2016-09-26T23:24:35.321Z] Session [61de22a0-8440-11e6-9376-7b90c4d612ac] - page.onError - stack:
  onUpdate (http://exmaple.com/xyz_search.jsp:166)
  updateData (http://exmaple.com/table_ss.js:411)
  render (http://exmaple.com/table_ss.js:340)
  selectTable (http://exmaple.com/xyz_search.jsp:285)
  onclick (http://exmaple.com/xyz_search.jsp:741)
  dispatchEvent (:0)
  U (:119)
  $ (:108)
  $ (:101)
  gh (:141)
  sh (:152)
  (anonymous function) (:152)
  (anonymous function) (:152)
  (anonymous function) (:153)

  phantomjs://platform/console++.js:263 in error
```

I am trying to figure out why it is throwing error instead showing result but no luck yet.Anyone has any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: The error is due to the version of PhantomJS you're using not having `String.prototype.startsWith`.  I don't seem to be able to locate exactly where it's occurring in your code, is there a specific line to focus on.  Perhaps you can change the way you're requesting that dom element.

Comment: @ R.A.Lucas:Error is occurring due to "datasetbutton.click();" line. If you remove that line then you will not get error but i need that 'click' to generate result. So which Phantomjs is compatible with Selenium 2.53.1 version ?

Comment: Is there possibly an alternative way to finding that element, as that's where I think the issue lies?  I'm unsure if there's a newer version of PhantomJS that has the `startsWith` ES6 method.

Answer (score 0):

This is because phantomjs had no polyfill (Function.prototype.bind) function in its javascript engine. Now it has (since 2.1). Try to download the [latest phantomjs release](http://phantomjs.org/download.html).